# How I can get parity logs for non-mainchain blocks?

Tags: parity, events

There's no much info on how parity event log works. What happens to event logs that correspond to block which is not mainchain anymore? Are they unrecoverably lost? For such an occasion, is there any way to reproduce event logs(not traces) from a given block or transaction?